# how to solve "No module named 'ConfigParser'" issue?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, openstack, apt-get

On ubuntu 16.4 server, I am using python3:

```
which python3
/usr/bin/python3

ls -l /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Nov 11  2021 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.7
```

and when I do **apt-get install** as root user, I have seen such failure:

**apt-get install python3-openstackclient**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-openstackclient is already the newest version (2.3.1-0ubuntu1).
Suggested packages:
  libglib2.0-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libglib2.0-dev
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 214 not upgraded.
292 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,375 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,072 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 157407 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-dev_2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-dev_2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-dev_2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can someone help me with that.

Thanks a lot.

Jack

Comment: I believe the version of `libglib2.0-dev` is using Python 2. Could you try uninstalling that and reinstalling it?

Comment: @user3595231 try to use the pip-package instead of the apt-packages for the client: `pip3 install python-openstackclient`.